# Запуск нескольких аккаунтов ботов с параллельным выполнением задач на telethon

Tags: python, многопоточность, асинхронность, telethon

Задача - запустить несколько ботов, чтобы они автономно выполняли свою задачу, параллельно друг с другом.

```
import asyncio
from threading import Thread
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
import time
import datetime as dt

api_id = 11111111
api_hash = '000000000000000000000000000000000'

async def work(client):
    async with client:
        me = await client.get_me()
        starttime = time.time()
        while True:
            print('Working with', me.first_name)
            delay = 0.01
            time.sleep(delay - ((time.time() - starttime) % delay))


async def main():
    threadlist = []
    users = []
    users.append(TelegramClient('user1', api_id, api_hash))
    users.append(TelegramClient('user2', api_id, api_hash))
    for u in users:
        threadlist.append(Thread(target=work, args=(u,)))   
    for t in threadlist:
        t.start()
    for t in threadlist:
        t.join()


asyncio.run(main())
```

При выполнении данного кода work() не выполняется, и выдает данную ошибку

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 910
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'work' was never awaited
```

До этого не работал с многопоточностью, поэтому прошу вашей помощи.

Comment: а для нескольких ботов есть несколько токенов ?

Comment: апи это для виртуального устройства, а инфа о логининых ботах хранится отдельно в session

Comment: точнее, у каждого бота свой уникальный токен, да

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте запускать корутину в самом потоке.

```
import asyncio
from threading import Thread
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
import time
import datetime as dt

api_id = 11111111
api_hash = '000000000000000000000000000000000'

async def work(client):
    async with client:
        me = await client.get_me()
        starttime = time.time()
        while True:
            print('Working with', me.first_name)
            delay = 0.01
            time.sleep(delay - ((time.time() - starttime) % delay))

def main(client):
    asyncio.run(work(client))


threadlist = []
users = []
users.append(TelegramClient('user1', api_id, api_hash))
users.append(TelegramClient('user2', api_id, api_hash))
for u in users:
    threadlist.append(Thread(target=main, args=(u,)))
for t in threadlist:
    t.start()
for t in threadlist:
    t.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import asyncio
from threading import Thread
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
import time
import datetime as dt

api_id = 111111111
api_hash = '222222222222222222222222222222222'

async def start(username):
    async def work():
        Work = "Something"
    
    client = TelegramClient(username, api_id, api_hash)
    async with client:
        await work()



def main(client):
    asyncio.run(start(client))



threadlist = []
users = []
for i in range(1,3):
    users.append("user"+str(i))
for u in users:
    threadlist.append(Thread(target=main, args=(u,)))
for t in threadlist:
    t.start()
for t in threadlist:
    t.join()
```

Достаточно просто передавать само имя пользователя в многопоток, и затем его идентифицировать уже отдельно